# Regular Expression for name field

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am using this code but it doesn't work correctly for - (mains) symbol

```
^\b\w{1,}(_\.-)?\w\b$ or ^\b\w{1,}(_\.\-)?\w\b$
```

The code above doesn't work if string is like this: name-name

What I want to do with this code is:
Name most begin with Alphanumeric and aslo end, it can have this symbols (.-_) but only in the middle

```
name => true
Name_ => false
Name_sa => true
name._ => false  
name.-as => false
```

Comment: The input[name] is for comment and free for all visitors :) that's why :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
^[^\W_]+([_.-][^\W_]+)?$
```

Here the `[^\W_]` matches only any character except non-word characters and the `_`, so basically any word character except `_`. This is necessary as `\w` does contain `_`.

Comment: And a `?` after the `[_.-]` to match words without the special character in the middle.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The first `+` covers it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with that regex:

- You are forgetting to allow multiple repetitions of the final \w
- You are only allowing one of those special symbols inside name

Also, instead of {1,} you can also use +, which makes it more readable. So this regex should achieve what you want:

> /^\b\w[\w_.-]*\w\b$/

Comment: Note that `_` is part of the `\w` character class so you can omit mentioning it explicitly (and that underscore will match at the start/end).

Answer (score 0):

`name-name` should work. If you want something like `name.-as` to work, you need to change the `?` to `*` to allow for multiple characters in the middle.

Comment: Nah, he doesn't want `name.-as` to work. Marked as false in his question.

Comment: @SebastianWramba I think you're right. It wasn't clear that the examples given were desired output.